# Plsql not declared error, even tough it should be declared

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hello im new to Plsql and I try to get a new Id for a new Employee

This is the Table emp:

```
EMPNO             NUMBER(4)    
ENAME             VARCHAR2(10) 
JOB               VARCHAR2(9)  
MGR               NUMBER(4)    
HIREDATE          DATE         
SAL               NUMBER(7,2)  
COMM              NUMBER(7,2)  
DEPTNO   NOT NULL NUMBER(2)
```

This is my Function

```
DECLARE 
 empno number;
FUNCTION findNewEmpno  
RETURN number 
IS 
    empno number; 
BEGIN 
   select Max(empno)
   into empno from emp;
END; 
BEGIN 
   dbms_output.put_line(' New Empno is : ' || empno); 
END; 
/
```

And this is the error message I get:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 13, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'FINDNEWEMPNO' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 13, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
```

I have no Idea why FINDNEWEMPNO is not decleared.
The Function is above the point where it gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be like this:

- create a function
- call it

---

```
SQL> create or replace function findnewempno
  2    return number
  3  is
  4    v_empno number;
  5  begin
  6    select max(empno)
  7      into v_empno
  8      from emp;
  9
 10    return v_empno;
 11  end;
 12  /

Function created.

SQL> select findnewempno from dual;

FINDNEWEMPNO
------------
        7934

SQL>
```

Or, as you tried to *display* it:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> begin
  2    dbms_output.put_line('Max EMPNO = ' || findnewempno);
  3  end;
  4  /
Max EMPNO = 7934

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```